# 400 Bad Request when publishing forms in odk aggregate

Tags: odk

> Error: RequestFailureException (com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant" })

I am getting this error when trying to publish the forms in odk aggregate.I have included basic APIs (Drive,fusion,google map) only.  Using aggregate 1.4.5 version.

Comment: error log trace is here:

Comment: Post the error log...

Answer (score 1):

I was just encountering the same error. I realized that I was not inputting the correct email address in the "Google API Credentials Upload" window. I was putting my regular (`@gmail.com`) address instead of the service (`@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) address. Once I changed the email address everything else worked.

p.s. I found the service account email for my project at `https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts?project=NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT_HERE`

Comment: Where does aggregate publish the results to if you use the service account address?

Answer (score 0):

1. change your email address to project address found here https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=PROJECTNAME
2. Don't forget to copy link to 'Get Token' in an incognito window to the get the new token.